# ng-recaptcha ERR: Error: "Uncaught (in promise): [object Null]"

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha

I am using ng-recaptcha package in order to implement Google reCAPTCHA V3 in my web app.
For that I created a Service with will perform all the needed actions on the client side.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReCaptchaV3Service, OnExecuteData } from 'ng-recaptcha';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


const BACKEND_URL = environment.apiUrl + '/contact/';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private recaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service
    ) {}

    public sendContactForm(data): void {
        this.recaptchaV3Service.execute('contactForm').subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });

        // this.http.post(BACKEND_URL, data)
        //     .subscribe((responseData) => {
        //         console.log(responseData);
        //     });
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, when executing recaptcha (on sendContactForm method), I get the following error:

"Uncaught (in promise): [object Null]"

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: can you create a sample demo on stackblitz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google reCaptcha response "Uncaught (in promise) null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390562/google-recaptcha-response-uncaught-in-promise-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This errors occurs when a site is not "registered" in the Google recaptcha/admin Domains area.

**Solution: Add the domain in the recaptcha admin area:**

1. Sign into your Google account where your recaptcha keys are registered
2. Type into Google "google recpatcha admin console"
3. Go to your settings for your (production) key
4. In "Domains", add these two entries:

> ```
> localhost
> 127.0.0.1
> ```

5. Save it and test your recaptcha.

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390562/google-recaptcha-response-uncaught-in-promise-null) that asks the same thing and requires the same solution.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much. Waiting so long for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your domain to the recaptcha admin [console](https://www.google.com/u/1/recaptcha/admin).

Don't forget to add `localhost`  for your test.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much. Waiting so long for an answer.